# Dependency between plugins? Calling a method before plugin is created

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, jquery-plugins, dom-events

I have 2 plugins, 1 of them is always there, the other not. During the initialization of plugin 2, I try to access a settings variable from plugin 1, but get an error because plugin 1 hasn't been created yet (load order). i.e.:

```
;(function$) {
    $.plugin2 = function(el, options) {
        ...
        ...
        var init = function() {
        plugin.settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
        plugin.el = el;

        var init = function() {
            ...plugin1Instance.settings.variable... <--------
        }

        init();
    };
});
```

Would prefer not doing the timeOut method, was wondering what would be the cleanest way of going about this.

Answer (score 0):

I makes plugins load this way.
May it will useful for someone.

In global section define array

var plugins = [];

Load all my plugins (*.js) as usual, `<script type="text/javascript" src="pluginX.js"></script>`

Each pluginX.js add his init() function to plugins array.

And onload document body event handler loop thru plugins array and call each added function.

So, we wait till document was load all scripts, and then continue.

Code in global section:

```
var plugins = [];

function startOnLoad() {
   // Start init() of every 'registered; plugin
   for (var i = 0; plugins.length - 1; i++) {
      plugins[i]();
   }

   // Ok, all plugins initialized, can access each other.
   // Ex: plugin1Instance.settings.variable and etc.
}
```

In each pluginX.js an the end:

```
plugins.push(Plugin1.init);
```

PS: Load plugins after section where plugins array defined.

Answer (score 0):

If your plugins are placed in external files then listening for onload event should be enough:

```
var windowOnLoad = function() {
    // your plugins should be loaded at the moment
}
if (window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener('load', windowOnLoad, false);
} else if (window.attachEvent) {
    window.attachEvent('onload', windowOnLoad);
}
```

If that doesn't work for some reason you should edit your plugins and get notification once they are initialized.

```
var totalPlugins = 2;
var numberOfLoadedPlugins = 0;
var pluginLoaded = function() {
    numberOfLoadedPlugins += 1;
    if(numberOfLoadedPlugins === totalPlugins) {
        // it's done. your plugins are loaded
        // proceed with the other logic
    }
}

;(function$) {
    $.plugin1 = function(el, options) {
        // ...
    };
    pluginLoaded();
});
;(function$) {
    $.plugin2 = function(el, options) {
        // ...
    };
    pluginLoaded();
});
```

You should find the entry point of your application and stop there, wait till the plugins are loaded and continue.